# Beginner stuck on jQuery/JS and would love some assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a quiz app using JavaScript, jQuery, html, and CSS. I'm trying to get the questions and answer choices to load and am having trouble.

Can anyone help me with editing the "generateQuestion" function in my JS file: https://github.com/em-ilylewis/Quiz-App/blob/master/store.js.

Here is the html as well: https://github.com/em-ilylewis/Quiz-App/blob/master/question-page.html.

Comment: please add your code here and describe what does not work for you

Comment: I'm all set now, but thank you so much, anyways!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Going line by line in the comments above the `generateQuestion` function should help break it down:
*1. get the object from the store at the questionNumber index*
Since **STORE** is an array, you can access individual items in that array like so:

```js
// This will get you the FIRST item in your STORE array.
STORE[0]
```

And since we already know that the `questionNumber` variable is set to `0` (on line 77) you can do this:

```js
// This will get you the FIRST item in your STORE array.
STORE[questionNumber]
```

*2. use jQuery to select the element with the class questionBox*

```js
// This is correctly targeting the questionBox element
$(".questionBox")
```

*3. use the html function on the jQuery element from the previous step to fill that element with the question string from the object you got out of the store*
- Now you can use object-dot notation to access an object's values using its key property, like so:

```js
// This will get you the first item's "question" in your STORE's array (assuming it is still 0).
$(".questionBox").html(STORE[questionNumber].question);
```

Unfortunately, this only solves your problem for getting the *first* item in your STORE array. So you'll likely want to pass in the *index* of the STORE array by using *arguments* from your `generateQuestion` function, like so:

```js
// "index" is an argument of generateQuestion.
function generateQuestion(index) {
  $(".questionBox").html(STORE[index].question);
  $(".answerChoiceBox").html(STORE[index].choices);
}
generateQuestion(0); // Passing in 0 as a parameter of generateQuestion will get you the FIRST question in your array.
generateQuestion(1); // ...SECOND question
generateQuestion(2); // ...THIRD question
```

Comment: it now works, you are amazing, you have made my weekend, and have restored my faith in humanity. Haha. Thank you!!!!!!